# Build (Assembly kits?) the frame of a robot

Tags: manufacturing, frame

I am fairly knowledgeable about robotics programming, and stuff like that; but, I am a total ignorant about how to actually "build" a robot.

My question is: What materials do you recommend to build a robot and where can I buy them. It does not matter *what kind* of robot. I know that a robotic arm is very different from a mobile robot.  I know the theory.

Other than Lego bricks (which I have heard of), I am imaging silicon frames... I really don't know.

I have developed some very fair and nice devices with image processing, computer vision and stuff. I also know how to program several kinds of motors etc. 
*I just don't know how to put all of this inside a nice frame and show it to the world*

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* KansaiRobot, but I'm afraid that questions like this are off-topic because there there is no answer which could be considered *correct*. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: I am sorry but "what do you use to build your robots" is off-topic? There are people building robots with several materials and I can not ask them what do they use? really?

Comment: Ask yourself, is there a correct answer to your question? How can someone decide whether an answer to your question is correct or not. As it says in [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): *If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much* and *avoid asking subjective questions where …* This advice holds true for every stack exchange site.

Comment: One supplier that has great T Slot aluminum is MB Kit Systems - https://mbkit.com/profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentor several FTC (First Tech Challenge) Robotics Teams.  These teams build medium size robots (about 50cm cube starting size).

For this size, there are four Building Systems that are the most common

1. [Tetrix](https://www.tetrixrobotics.com/)
2. [Matrix](http://www.modernroboticsinc.com/matrix)
3. [Actobotics](https://www.servocity.com/actobotics)
4. [8020 Extrusions](https://www.8020.net/) (There are lots of other suppliers too)

These solutions are all very flexible allow a large about of options on how to build frames and attach motors, wheels, sensors, etc. and are designed for reuse.

Hotwired Robotics (one of our local FTC teams) wrote a great overview of the different [Building Systems](http://hotwiredrobotics.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/HW-Robot-Build-Systems.pdf).

---

**Shameless Plug**

Why not [find a First Robotics Team near you](https://www.firstinspires.org/team-event-search#type=teams&sort=name&programs=FLLJR,FLL,FTC,FRC&year=2017) and offer to be a help Mentor?  You can learn from them how to build a robot and they can learn from you how to program one.